# PostgreSQL 8.3: Slow GROUP BY on large table

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, group-by, postgresql-8.3, query-performance

I have a table with about 10 million records. I want to do a simple group by, but it's using a sequential scan and is slow...

```
select run_id, count(*) from result group by run_id;
```

I have an index defined on the `run_id` column.

How can I speed this up?

Answer (score 3):

So why does Postgres 9.2 still show a sequential scan? I quote the [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Is_.22count.28.2A.29.22_much_faster_now.3F):

> Is "count(*)" much faster now?
>
> A traditional complaint made of PostgreSQL, generally when comparing
>   it unfavourably with MySQL (at least when using the MyIsam storage
>   engine, which doesn't use MVCC) has been "count(*) is slow".
>   Index-only scans *can* be used to satisfy these queries without there
>   being any predicate to limit the number of rows returned, and without
>   forcing an index to be used by specifying that the tuples should be
>   ordered by an indexed column. However, in practice that isn't
>   particularly likely.
>
> It is important to realise that the planner is concerned with
>   minimising the total cost of the query. With databases, the cost of
>   I/O typically dominates. For that reason, "count(*) without any
>   predicate" queries will only use an index-only scan if the index is
>   significantly smaller than its table. **This typically only happens when
>   the table's row width is much wider than some indexes'**.

Emphasis mine.
There is hardly anything to gain from an index scan here, as long as your talbe isn't bloated with more (big) columns.

Comment: An index scan can improve the performance here *because* of the part you emphasized. If `run_id` is the only column in the index, a table row will very likely be much wider than then an index "row" (unless the table only has two or three columns) and thus scanning the index will require less I/O compared to a table scan (because it consists of fewer database blocks). To know this for sure we would need to see the table definition.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to PostgreSQL 9.2 overnight.

`EXPLAIN` still shows the query using a sequential scan, but the query seems to run much faster now... under 10 seconds. This will be sufficient for my needs.

Thanks to everyone for the help in the comments.